# How to change my repository in the git bash terminal? or How to change the directory?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, git-bash

[VS code terminal (Git Bash) image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5X717.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The directory you want to change to doesn't exists, as evident by the output of `cd`.

```
bash: cd: demo_repository: No such file or directory
```

Provide the proper path, you properly need to navigate one directory up first:

```
$ cd ../demo_repository
```

As you can see from your prompt:

[image]

You can see that your currect directory is `demo_repository2` (the path in yellow).